# Only fetch people who are not your friends

Tags: php, mysql

My code looks like this right now

```
<?php 
    $get_userinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id != '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
            $userinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_userinfo);
            $usertags = $userinfo['tags'];
            $tagsdata = explode(" ", $usertags);
            $interestsdata = explode(" ", $interests);
            $result = array_intersect($interestsdata, $tagsdata);

            echo '<li><img src="images/users/'.$userinfo['avatar'].'" /><a href="'.$userinfo['username'].'">'.$userinfo['name'].'</a><div class="add whotofollow'.$i.'" title="Not following/friends"></div></li>';
            }
?>
```

So this currently selects all users who not are yourself and then matches them against your interests in people so only people you actually want updates from are shown. Then it makes so only 6 out of all these people becomes visible and it doesn't check like so the one with most things in common places first and such.

There is a few things I myself doesn't know how to code from this.

I first need to make sure only people I have not added as friends are shown. Friends are stored in a table called "friends" containing the rows "userid" and "userid2". Either userid or userid2 can be my id if we are friends.

Secondly I need to order them so the one I have most in common with places first and also so the top 6 people with most in common with me are shown and not 6 random ones.

So basically, how do I first check so I haven't added them as friends? (table: friends, rows: userid and userid2, either id can be my id)
How do I select the top 6 people with most in common with me?

Comment: He already did that: _Friends are stored in a table called "friends" containing the rows "userid" and "userid2"._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To select only people who are no friends:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
     FROM friends
     WHERE userid = users.id
           OR userid2 = users.id)
```

For matching tags and comparing them, I would prefer a third table.

edit: something like

```
SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM friends WHERE userid = users.id OR userid2 = users.id)
    ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tags AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tags AS t2 ON t1.tagname = t2.tagname
        WHERE t1.id = users.id)
    LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Oh yeah, i forgot `EXISTS` statement, how dumb am i :(

Comment: Thank you! This helped but I don't want to show it as the answer because I still don't know how to take the top 6 people.

Comment: Without editing anything I get a error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT userid as uid FROM tags AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tags AS 51 ON t1.tagname = ' at line 4".
Either something is wrong in the code or I should add a table or change something I don't know.

Comment: as said, you need to add the tags table (userid | tagname)

Comment: I added the table tags_users and inside I've got (id, userid, tagname, type and date)
My query looks like this: $get_userinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM friends WHERE userid = users.id OR userid2 = users.id)
    ORDER BY COUNT(SELECT userid as uid FROM tags_users AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tags_users AS 51 ON t1.tagname = t2.tagname
        WHERE uid = users.id AND type = '2')
    LIMIT 6") or die (mysql_error()); and I get the same error.

Comment: please export your tables to a sql-file with some sample-data, so I can test it.

Comment: Thank you! Just one little thing, now the user it self also gets shown in the list, how do I remove myself? My code looks like this:
$get_userinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM friends WHERE userid = users.id OR userid2 = users.id)
    ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tags_users AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tags_users AS t2 ON t1.tagname = t2.tagname
        WHERE t1.id = users.id AND t1.type = '2') AND id != '$id'
    LIMIT 6") or die (mysql_error());
And the user itself still gets shown in the list.

Comment: try `users.id != '.$id.' AND NOT EXISTS ...`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two tables: `users` and `friends`. You want to match your `friends` matching your `userid` (I am assuming this is `userid2` in `friends`?) and display the user information from the table `users`.

The select statement below will return rows from the user table where the `userid` in the users table matches `userid` in the friends table and the `userid2` field equals your `username`. The `limit` statement will show only the first 6 matches

```
SELECT * FROM users
JOIN friends ON users.userid == friends.userid WHERE friends.userid2 == '$id'
LIMIT 6
```

This doesn't address sorting by the most matches of friends. I'll leave that to someone else.